# How to disable "Flip screen" in a Toshiba Satellite Radius P55W-B5224 laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, touchpad, toshiba-laptop

Every time I hold my laptop and *make any movement* with it (i.e. on my lap or hands) or after **closing the laptop lid** or after **rotating screen**, the keyboard and touchpad stop working. After this, the only way to enable them again is restarting the operating system. Such problem occurs with both windows or linux OS's. I am wondering if disabling the system driver related to the "flip-and-fold" function will avoid the problem with the keyboard and mouse. And how could I do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You already messed with the touchpad driver settings? It might be worth a shot to uninstall and reinstall those drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve this problem (apparently) just by commenting a function in `*iio-sensor-proxy*` service (I'm using elementary OS loki) which controls *[auto-screen rotation](http://askubuntu.com/a/864783/191546)*. See step-by-step [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/864783/191546) (askubuntu.com/a/864783/191546). I don't no why and how but I think accelerometer may be related to touchpad and keyboard malfunction in this laptop. 
By the way, I don't advise anyone to buy Toshiba's (Satellite Radius) laptop, it sucks!